# Why the grad is unavailable for the tensor in gpu

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd, computation-graph

```
a = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.ones(5, 5))
a = a.cuda()
print(a.requires_grad)
b = a
b = b - 2
print('a ', a)
print('b ', b)
loss = (b - 1).pow(2).sum()
loss.backward()
print(a.grad)
print(b.grad)
```

After executing codes, the `a.grad` is `None` although `a.requires_grad` is `True`.
But if the code `a = a.cuda()` is removed, `a.grad` is available after the loss backward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The .grad attribute of a Tensor that is not a leaf Tensor is being accessed. Its .grad attribute won't be populated during autograd.backward(). If you indeed want the gradient for a non-leaf Tensor, use .retain_grad() on the non-leaf Tensor. If you access the non-leaf Tensor by mistake, make sure you access the leaf Tensor instead. See github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/30531 for more information.

```py
a = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.ones(5, 5))
a = a.cuda()
print(a.requires_grad)
b = a
b = b - 2
print('a ', a)
print('b ', b)
loss = (b - 1).pow(2).sum()

a.retain_grad() # added this line

loss.backward()
print(a.grad)
```

That happens because of your line `a = a.cuda()` that override the original value of `a`.

You could use

```py
a = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.ones(5, 5))
a.cuda()
```

Or

```py
a = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.ones(5, 5, device='cuda'))
```

```py
a = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.ones(5, 5).cuda())
```

Or explicitly requesting to retain the gradients of `a`

```py
a.retain_grad() # added this line
```

Erasing the gradients of intermediate variables can save significant amount of memory. So it is good that you retain gradients only where you need.

Comment: I hope you can accept the answer, if you need take a look on the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)